# search query in elasticsearch with url in field

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, querydsl

I have to search a file location path in the indexed data of an elastic search. I indexed the location path in an encoded format(tried without encoding also). The below query returns all the indexed data without doing any match. If I search with **id** or **title** field, it returns correct result.Do anyone have any idea?

```
{
"query": {
     "match": {
     "location": "%5c%5c25.94.150.212%5cfoldername%5cintroduction_to_c_sharp.ppt"
    }
}
}
```

Response I got from browser http://localhost:9200/documents

```
{
  "documents": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "indexdocument": {
        "properties": {
          "document": {
            "type": "attachment",
            "fields": {
              "content": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "author": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "keywords": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "content_type": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "content_length": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "language": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "documentType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "lastModifiedDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1465193502636",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "5kCRvhmsQAGyndkswLhLrg",
        "version": {
          "created": "2030399"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

Create Index code which is having one field attachment:

```
        public void CreateDocumentIndex()
           {
               this.client.CreateIndex("documents", c =>  c.Mappings(mp=>mp.Map<IndexDocument>
                   (m => m.Properties(ps => ps.Attachment
                                       (a => a.Name(o => o.Document)
                                             .TitleField(t => t.Name(x =>     x.Title).TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))
                                              )))));
  }
```

Properties to index

```
 public class IndexDocument
   {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    // Base64-encoded file content.
    public string Document { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    [Nest.String(Store = true, Index = Nest.FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string Location { get; set; }        
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `location` field is `not_analyzed`, you can use a `term` query instead of a `match`.

```
{
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "location": "%5c%5c25.94.150.212%5cfoldername%5cintroduction_to_c_sharp.ppt"
      }
   }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to make your `location` field `not_analyzed` (see below) and reindex your data.

```
PUT your_index/_mapping/your_type
{
  "properties": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the below `term` query

```
{
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "location.raw": "%5c%5c25.94.150.212%5cfoldername%5cintroduction_to_c_sharp.ppt"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How can I make my location field not_analysed?

Comment: I set the property like this [Nest.String(Store = false, Index = Nest.FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
        public string Location { get; set; } Then searched with the above query.Now no  rows are returned.

Comment: You need to delete your index first, then re-run your code to create the index again and then reindex your data.

Comment: Did it. Still no change. I have given my indexing like this  this.client.CreateIndex("documents", c => c.Mappings(mp=>mp.Map<IndexDocument>
                 (m => m.Properties(ps => ps.Attachment
                                         (a => a.Name(o => o.Document)
                                                .TitleField(t => t.Name(x => x.Title).TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))
                                                .FileField(f=>f.Name(n=>n.Location).TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))
                                                )))));

Comment: Can you update your question with what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/documents` ?

Comment: I dont have curl.In browser localhost:9200/documents returns this   {"documents":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"indexdocument":{"properties":{"document":{"type":"attachment","fields":{"content":{"type":"string"},"author":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string","term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"},"name":{"type":"string"},"date":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"},"keywords":{"type":"string"},"content_type":{"type":"string"},"content_length":{"type":"integer"},"language":{"type":"string"}}},"documentType":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"long"},

Comment: "lastModifiedDate":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"},"location":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1465193502636","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"5kCRvhmsQAGyndkswLhLrg","version":{"created":"2030399"}}},"warmers":{}}}

Comment: That's why I said "update your question with the response" ;) Please do, as that doesn't belong into comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Your `location` field is still analyzed. Something must be wrong in your code.

Comment: I am not able to sort out the issue. I have added all my code. Can you please help

Comment: I think if you give a concrete mapping in the `CreateIndex` call, it overrides the defaults you've set on your fields. Try without the mappings in `CreateIndex` and see what happens.